# How to deal with org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take() hotspot?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, profiling

I am profiling my application running on tomcat using `visualvm`. I am calling one of the REST web service method which creates 5000 records into HBase and returns successful and failed count to the client.

After running visualvm CPU sampler I found out that `org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take()` is the hotspot method. Here is the screenshot of the hotspot methods.

[image]

Does anyone know how to deal with this hotspot method?

Comment: @apangin your comment could be translated to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a hot spot. Take a look at `Self time (CPU)` column - the method does not burn CPU, it just waits on a `Condition` object.